# Chrome Extension background.js only to work if user is cookie is available

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, setcookie

I want the background.js to only work if a certain cookie value is available,  if it is not, then the popup.html should prompt the user to login. I want only the popup.html to come appear only if that cookie value is not available. I am not using popup.js, should i use it in this case or it should be enough to embed my script in popup.html.

Please advise. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the [`chrome.cookies`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) API to check for presence of specific cookies from your background page.
- You can't embed javascript code in your popup.html, due to the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) for Chrome extensions. You need to put your code in a separate file like popup.js and include it via `<script src="popup.js></script>`